# Is there a way to force RTL Characters to be written as LTR in my font

Tags: unicode, arabic, arabic-support, fontforge

I want a way to force RTL(Right-To-Left) Characters to be written as LTR(Left-To-Right) when i type it.

for example if i typed:
سلام عليكم

it should be:
‭سلام عليكم

I can do this manually while typing by using LRO(LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE) control character(its code point is U+202D) that forces rtl characters to be like ltr.

But i need an automatic way to do this.

i think that their is a way to embed this behavior in my font so that it is done automatically while using my font.

Tell me any idea to do this if possible.

I use fontforge to make my fonts.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this automatically in the way you described. Directionality is determined by character properties, which fonts have no control over. You will have to resort to using the override controls or – if you are not limited to plain text – higher-level protocols, such as the CSS declaration `unicode-bidi: bidi-override`.